# Appending the output of a variable to the end of a specific line

Tags: bash

Within my template(callbacks), there is a line that ends with "IP:" I would like to append to. I tried this command:

```
cat callbacks | grep "IP:" | cut -d ":" -f 2 | echo $(ping -c2 host.com).
```

I thought i would be able to echo something at the end, but that didn't work. Could someone please shed some light on what i am doing wrong.

This is what i have so far:

```
for textfile in $(find . -iname "2013*-malware-callback*.txt")
    do cat callbacks | cat - $textfile > tmpfile && mv tmpfile $textfile
done
```

Comment: Please improve your question by including whatever samples you're using as a corpus to test against. Also, include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The following takes the contents of `$textfile`, finds any occurrence of IP: and appends to it an IP address, and saves the result in tmpfile:

```
v="1.2.3.4"
cat "$textfile" | sed 's/IP:/IP: '"$v/" >tmpfile
```

The pipeline can be simplified:

```
sed 's/IP:/IP: '"$v/" <"$textfile" >tmpfile
```

Further, if the ultimate goal is to replace $textfile with the modified version, we can use sed's modify-in-place feature:

```
sed -i.bak 's/IP:/IP: '"$v/" "$textfile"
```

This modifies $textfile in place and, for safekeeping, leaves a backup copy of the original with extension .bak.